# Executing command on 2 or 3 consecutive Eye Blinks using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, detection, eye-detection

I'm working on a project of Executing commands ( right now just printing " User Clicked: YES " ) when the Paralyzed patient Blinks 2-consecutive times or 3-consecutive times.
For the eye-blink detection i used the code from "Adrian Rosebrock" which can be found on pyimagesearch site. I've modified it a lot but i'm stuck at the logic of detecting 2-consecutive blinks or 3-consecutive blinks.
I can't seem to find a way to detect them in a video or LiveStream from Webcam.
The idea behind this concept is presented in the image:
[Image of the Blinking Idea Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4kt7.jpg). As input i take a video of a person blinking a single-time for once, then he blinks two-consecutive times , then three-consecutive times. My purpose is to detect all of those blinks. Categorize the double blinks simultaneously as 2-blinks. And also categorize the three blinks simultaneously as 3-blinks. After that i'll assign some commands. The single blink will have a different command to execute. The double blinks will have different command and the triple blinks will have a different command to execute.
 The entire code is below:

```
# import the necessary packages
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils import face_utils
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import timeit
import time
import dlib
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import sys

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
click = 'YES'

def eye_aspect_ratio(eye):
    # compute the euclidean distances between the two sets of
    # vertical eye landmarks (x, y)-coordinates
    A = dist.euclidean(eye[1], eye[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye[2], eye[4])

    # compute the euclidean distance between the horizontal
    # eye landmark (x, y)-coordinates
    C = dist.euclidean(eye[0], eye[3])

    # compute the eye aspect ratio
    ear = (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

    # return the eye aspect ratio
    return ear

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
#   help="path to facial landmark predictor")
# ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str, default="",
#   help="path to input video file")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())
shape_predictor =  filedialog.askopenfilename()

video = filedialog.askopenfilename()


USER_INPUT = input("Please select a mode 1 = Single Blink , 2 = Double Blink, 3 = Triple Blink:\n ")
# define two constants, one for the eye aspect ratio to indicate
# blink and then a second constant for the number of consecutive
# frames the eye must be below the threshold
EYE_AR_THRESH = 0.3
# if USER_INPUT == "1":
#   EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 6
# elif USER_INPUT == "2":
#   EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 3
# elif USER_INPUT == "3":
#   EYE_AR_CONSEC_FRAMES = 0

# initialize the frame counters and the total number of blinks
COUNTER = 0
TOTAL = 0
D_TOTAL = 0
D_COUNT = 0
T_TOTAL = 0
SPEED_BLINK_COUNTER = 0
S_blink = []
S_blink_show = 0
click = ''
D_blink = []
D_time = []


# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
print("[INFO] loading facial landmark predictor...")
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
#predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])
predictor =  dlib.shape_predictor(shape_predictor)


# grab the indexes of the facial landmarks for the left and
# right eye, respectively
(lStart, lEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["left_eye"]
(rStart, rEnd) = face_utils.FACIAL_LANDMARKS_IDXS["right_eye"]

# start the video stream thread
print("[INFO] starting video stream thread...")
#vs = FileVideoStream(args["video"]).start()
vs = FileVideoStream(video).start()

#fileStream = True
#vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
#vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
fileStream = False
time.sleep(1.0)

# loop over frames from the video stream
while True:
    # if this is a file video stream, then we need to check if
    # there any more frames left in the buffer to process
    if fileStream and not vs.more():
        break

    # grab the frame from the threaded video file stream, resize
    # it, and convert it to grayscale
    # channels)
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=450)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # detect faces in the grayscale frame
    rects = detector(gray, 0)

    # loop over the face detections
    for rect in rects:
        # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
        # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
        # array
        shape = predictor(gray, rect)
        shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

        # extract the left and right eye coordinates, then use the
        # coordinates to compute the eye aspect ratio for both eyes
        leftEye = shape[lStart:lEnd]
        rightEye = shape[rStart:rEnd]
        leftEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(leftEye)
        rightEAR = eye_aspect_ratio(rightEye)

        # average the eye aspect ratio together for both eyes
        ear = (leftEAR + rightEAR) / 2.0

        # compute the convex hull for the left and right eye, then
        # visualize each of the eyes
        leftEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(leftEye)
        rightEyeHull = cv2.convexHull(rightEye)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [leftEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        cv2.drawContours(frame, [rightEyeHull], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)

        # check to see if the eye aspect ratio is below the blink
        # threshold, and if so, increment the blink frame counter
        # Jb tk Ankh bnd hy to ye Counter increase hta jay ga kuink for loop lga hy
        if ear < EYE_AR_THRESH:
            COUNTER += 1


        # otherwise, the eye aspect ratio is not below the blink
        # threshold
        # Jese e Ankh khulay gi aur counter 3 frames ya is sy zyada hjay ga to Total mai increment ajaye ga
        else:
            # if the eyes were closed for a sufficient number of
            # then increment the total number of blinks

            if USER_INPUT == "1" and COUNTER >= 2:
                S_blink.append(TOTAL + 1)
                S_blink_show = sum(S_blink)
                #TOTAL += 1
                #S_blink = 1

            if USER_INPUT == "2" and  COUNTER >= 2:
                D_blink = S_blink.append(TOTAL + 1)

                if D_blink is not None:
                    for i in D_blink:
                        D_time.append(timeit.timeit(str(D_blink[i]), number=1000))

                if D_time is not None:
                    for i in D_time:
                        if D_time[i+1] < D_time[i]:
                        #if timeit.timeit(str(D_blink[i+1]), number=1000) < timeit.timeit(str(D_blink[i]), number=1000):
                            D_COUNT += 1



            if USER_INPUT == "3" and  COUNTER == 0.5 :
                T_TOTAL += 1

            # reset the eye frame counter
            COUNTER = 0
            #S_blink = 0

        # draw the total number of blinks on the frame along with
        # the computed eye aspect ratio for the frame
        MODE_text = "Blink Mode"
        MODE1_text = "Single Blink Mode"
        MODE2_text = "Double Blink Mode"
        MODE3_text = "Triple Blink Mode"

        if USER_INPUT == "1":
            SPEED_BLINK_COUNTER = S_blink_show
            MODE_text = MODE1_text
            #if S_blink == 1 :
                #click = "YES"
            #else:
                #click =""
        elif USER_INPUT == "2":
            SPEED_BLINK_COUNTER = D_COUNT
            MODE_text = MODE2_text
            # if TOTAL == 0 and D_TOTAL >= 1 and COUNTER == 0:
            #   click = "YES"
            # else:
            #   click =""
        elif USER_INPUT == "3":
            SPEED_BLINK_COUNTER = T_TOTAL
            MODE_text = MODE3_text
            # if COUNTER == 1:
            #   click = "YES"
            # else:
            #   click =""

        cv2.putText(frame, "Blinks: {}".format(SPEED_BLINK_COUNTER), (10, 30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (0, 250), (450, 350), (104, 104, 104), thickness=-1, lineType=8, shift=0)
        cv2.putText(frame, "User Clicked: {}".format(click), (220, 270),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame, MODE_text, (10, 270),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)



    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break

# do a bit of cleanup
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

After the comment by Sir Furas, i have changed the code. And this is what i came up with. I'm right now stuck at comparing the list of blink-time with one another. A repetition of the same subtraction is caused among the index values while they should all go by smoothly according to their place.

```
    if COUNTER >= 2:
        S_blink.append(TOTAL + 1)
        S_blink_show = sum(S_blink)
        end = time.time()
        blink_time.append(end - start)
        # print("Blink time: " + str(blink_time))
        print("This is [::]: " + str(blink_time[::]))
        print("This is [1:]: " + str(blink_time[1:]))
        for i, j in zip(blink_time[0:], blink_time[1:]):
            #print("I'm i: " + str(i), "I'm j: " + str(j))
            time_mid.append(j - i)
            print("Time Medium: " + str(time_mid))
```

I'm out of ideas now. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: what means "didn't work"? If you get error message then show it in question, not in comment. Using `time.time()` for this seems the only method.

Comment: I used time.time but it only notes down time for a command that is passed down to it. While a single blink takes the entire code to run. So how was i able to implement that and calculate its time?

Comment: you use `start = time.time()` befor code and `end = time.time()` after code and then  `end - start` gives you time of execution of this code. The same way you can use `previouse_blink = time.time()` and `current_blink = time.time()` to calculate time between two blinks - `current_blink - previouse_blink`. If time is lower then some value then you can treat them as 2-consecutive blinks which should run some command.

Comment: wow thank you so much. I will try it and let you know of the outcome. Thanks

Comment: @furas sir, the way i implemented the code is:
I have a video of a person blinking 1 time ( b1 ) in first few seconds, then blinking two-consecutive times ( b2 and b3 ) for a few seconds .......then blinking three-consecutive times.
The way i coded it is....I took down the time for a single-blink.....then the two-consecutive blinks......Then i subtracted the times of b3-b2 to get their time. Then i did the same for b2-b1 to get their time. Now i'm trying to do is to compare these times. I'm using Lists for all of this. But now i'm using for loop to access them and its not working as expected